# Ajax is not running properly with XAMPP

Tags: php, ajax, xampp

I am trying to run the following code on Xampp:

```
const handleRequest = () => {
  var xmlObject = XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlObject.open("GET", "process.php", true);
  xmlObject.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (xmlObject.readyState == 4 && xmlObject.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = xmlObject.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlObject.send();
}
```

Comment: Is there anything in your console (F12) ?

Answer (score 1):

You **must** declare your object with `new` operator:

```
var xmlObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

Comment: Glad I could help. You could always manage it by yourself, if you would check you browser logs (F12 on most browsers, console-tab), so such questions will be not raise again. Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks again @jaro1989 :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var xmlObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

You Need To Have The **new** Keyword

Answer (score 1):

In order to make your code work you need to add operator "new" in front of "XMLHttpRequest()" call.

Correct code:

```
var xmlObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
```